# Are the $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and the set of polynomials with real coefficients $\mathbb{R}[x]$ homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

If we express $ \mathbb{R}[x]$ as a vector, don't we have an isometry?

$F:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $F(x)=(x_1, x_2, x_3,...)$

I know this is not possible for example between $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ since obviously they have different cardinality but I'm not sure why this shouldn't work for the reals. Also, I'm still unsure why it does not work for the integers but that's for another question.

Thanks

Comment: No. Polynomials only have a finite number of terms so you only get the finite sequences. The two also don't have the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces (uncountable vs. countable).

Comment: There is an isomorphism between polynomials of degree at most $d$ and $\mathbb R^{d+1}$, given by sending a polynomial to its sequence of coefficients, e.g. $t^2+4t+1\mapsto (1,4,1)\in \mathbb R^3$. People sometimes write $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ to mean the limit $\lim \mathbb Rd$ , that is, the space of sequences of real numbers $(a_n)$ such that there is an integer $M>0$ with $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq M$. With this notation, the map sending a polynomial to its coefficients gives an isomorphism between the vector space of real polynomials and $\mathbb R^{\infty}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan if $R^{n+1}$ is a finite dimension vector space, in that case would it be homeomorphic with $R_n[x]$ the polynomials of degree n?

Comment: @Gonzalo: you mean "isomorphic" (as a vector space), and yes, that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No. Polynomials only have a finite number of terms so you only get the finite sequences." Qiaochu Yuan

So F is not an isometry